# AutoScaling across AZ in AWS as a DR service

Tags: amazon-web-services

Is it possible to have ASG as a DR between two AZ? For example, I have 5 instance in AZ1 servicing requests. During the AZ outage, I wanted to spin-up the 5 Instances in AZ2 and serve the request. Is it possible to control the isntance spinning up in AZ2 if only AZ1 Fails ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use AWS AutoScaling across multiple AZ, but only in a specific Region.

> "Auto Scaling can work across multiple Availability Zones in an AWS
> Region, making it easier to automate increasing and decreasing of
> capacity."

If you are trying to have high availability you can use aws global services like AWS CloudFront or AWS Global Accelerator. Example Scenario:

[image: high availability diagram]